# Partitions mixing up

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mbr, gpt

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows 7. The problem is that Ubuntu is not detecting all of my partitions and basically clubs together many of them. The same thing is done by using GParted. However this problem does not arise while I am using Windows 7.

[image: 1]

I think this could be due to stray GPT data but am not sure how to take care of it.

Can someone help me figure this out ? The output of `fdisk -l` is as follows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x20000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        2048      206847      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          206848   146802687    73297920   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       146802688   625140399   239168856   42  SFS
```

However actually I have 4 partitions along with 25 gb unallocated space that I had thought to use for Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and couldn't find solution, so I recreated one of the partitions and everything was fine.

Comment: What do you mean by reacreated one ? The partitions show up in windows correctly but for some reason 2 of them along with the 25 gb unallocated space are coming up as 1 in gparted as well as when I try to install ubuntu.

Comment: When I said recreate I mean: delete one partition and create it again. Just see what partitions are mixed up and delete one of them and create it again. But don't forget to backup your data. Which softvare you are using on windows to check partitions.

Comment: I dont need any software to check them ... They are fully functional on windows.

Comment: you should consider using additional softvare such as magic partition, with that softvare (or something similar) you can check whether your partitions are ok. But if gparted is telling you that something is wrong, then something is wrong.

Comment: I suggest that you install the `gdisk` package and execute `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` and add the output to your question. That should list any partitions defined with GPT, including any that aren't in the protective MBR. _I recommend that you don't convert anything_. What version of Ubuntu are you installing? Can you tell us the error messages you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The 0x42 ("42" under the "Id" column in your fdisk output) partitions mean that your disk is using Microsoft's [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager), aka *dynamic disks.* This is a non-standard meta-partitioning scheme conceptually similar to Linux's Logical Volume Manager (LVM). Installing Linux to an LDM disk is difficult at best. Your best bet is to convert your LDM configuration to a more conventional partition scheme. This can be done with some Windows tools, such as [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) and perhaps one or two others. Note that this has nothing to do with GPT; your disk is definitely *not* in GPT format, and there's no evidence of stray GPT data from your `fdisk` output.